# Slider in Xamarin Forms does not slide on touch after transtateTo or TranslateX or TranslateY in IOS

Tags: xamarin, slider

I define in XAML a Slider:

''''

''''

It works fine in Android but not in IOS: if I translate any control in C# with .TranstateTo (X, Y);
except the Slider:

```
TrackBar.TranslateTo(0f, 100f);
```

It moves to the new position but it appears to be locked: It do not respond to the screen touch (the mouse into the simulator).

I tried to use properties like isEnabled, setting isVisible to false and then to true... but nothing

Any suggestion?
Thanks in advance

Comment: Sounds like touch detection is in the *initial bounds* of the control, before translation. You can verify this by sliding a small amount, such that the new location overlaps the old location. Does slide work in the area that is still within the original bounds? I recommend finding a layout that gets the control where you want, without using Translate.